# Formatting callback parameters in Flask's dynamic routing

Tags: python, api, flask, spotify

Spotify's API returns authorisation code generated after user's verification in the following format:

**<customer_callback_URL>?code=1234567**

To capture the code in my Flask app, I've created a dynamic URL:

```
@app.route("/<auth_code>")
def callback_code(auth_code):
    return auth_code
```

Unfortunately, after receiving correct callback, the URL in the browser's address bar looks like   this:
**http://127.0.0.1:5000/?code=1234567**

Unfortunately, the dynamic URL ending *?code=1234567* is not generated and Flask server generates 404 error.

This is due to parameters (preceded by "?") are present in the callback URI. That makes the **callback_code** function unable to return the **?code=1234567** function of the URI.

How can I capture either the callback code string or callback's parameters, so that I can use the authorisation code in the other parts of my Flask app?

Answer (score 0):

That code is part of the query string.  What you want is:

```
@app.route("/")
def callback_code():
    return request.args.get('code')
```

Note that you are sending this to the root url, which is probably not what you want.  But it is OK if you don't mind testing every call for the `code` param

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if request.args.get('code'):
        # test for match and authorize
    else:
        # it's just a normal call to your domain's root url
```

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!